# JavaScript tCal date format

Tags: javascript, html, css, calendar, jtcalendar

I'm using tcal JS calendar on my website. I included tcal.css and tcal.js.

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" Name="DOB" class="tcal" required="yes">
```

The calendar displays correct, but it doesn't format the date. If I type 08031985, I would like that it automatically format to 08/03/1985. I don't want to have to enter the "/". Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting you correctly, you are not supposed to type the date but just pick it from the drop down pop up with the calendar.